# query a dictionary by a data member of a class in C# by LINQ

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

I am working on C# Win 7.

I need to get a query from a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, myClass> myDict;

public class myClass
{
   public int myId;
   public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>> Dict1;
}

var query = from myStr in myDict group by myStr.value.myId into g select g;
```

I got error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type keyValuePair  becasue it is not a delegate type.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from myStr in myDict 
            group myStr by myStr.Value.myId into g // you missed myStr here
            select g;
```

That is required by syntax of query expressions (C# Specification 7.16):

> ```
> group-clause:
>     group expression by expression
> ```

Comment: thanks ! the returned var is a new dictionary with myID as key ? if yes, what is its associated value for a key ? i need to know what Dict1 and its sub-dictionary<string, string[]> are associated with teh same myID.

Comment: @user2420472 returned value will be groups of `KeyValuePair` items from `myDict` dictionary. You can get grouping key by reading `.Key` property of each group

Comment: for the returned keyValuePair, if key is myID, what is the associated value ? thanks !

Comment: @user2420472 query will return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, KeyValuePair<string, myClass>>>`. Each group will have `g.Key` equal to grouping `myId` value. Group will contain keyvaluepairs from your dictionary - each will have it's own key and value (another dictionary).

Comment: for the returned IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, KeyValuePair<string, myClass>>>, if I have same int and same string, how the myClass is orgnized ? it is a list or an array ? what if I myClass is duplicted ? thanks !

Comment: how to iterate each value by key for the returned IEnumerable<> ?  I have to transform it to a dictionary ? Thanks !